# How can I get specific fields from user object in the REST API?

Tags: 8, users

I have a question about retrieving fields from the user object using REST in Drupal 8. When i am logged in into Drupal i can use the following GET call too retrieve the user object:

http://localhost:8081/user/2?_format=json

This will return a json response with all the fields of this user. I only want to retrieve 3 fields and not the whole object.

How can i set some specific fields too return and not all the fields?

Comment: If this is the only thing you want to get via JSON then write a custom JSON controller. If this is only the start of a much bigger project then look for a different web service implementation. See https://dri.es/headless-cms-rest-vs-jsonapi-vs-graphql

Comment: Thanks @4k4, this is the only thing so i will build a JSON controller.